# Экспорт в xlsx laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть экспорт заявок таблица 'orders', foreach обогащает данные из других таблиц, проблема в том, что одинаковые данные из других таблиц он заменяет, а не добавляет, в чем может быть причина? я подозреваю что не правильно запрашиваю коллекцию
вот код

```
$orders = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->whereDate('order_date', '2021-08-19')->get();
    
    if ($orders->count()) {
        foreach ($orders as $order) {

            /* Контрагент */
            $counter = CounterAgent::find($order->counter_agent_id);
            if (!$counter) {
                continue;
            }
            
            /* Директор */
            $director = Name::find($counter->director_name_id);
            if (!$director) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $director_full_name = trim($director->last_name).' '.trim($director->first_name);
            $director_full_name .= ' '.trim($director->middle_name);
            
            /* Агент */
            $agent = Name::find($order->name_id);
            if (!$agent) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $agent_full_name = trim($agent->last_name).' '.trim($agent->middle_name);
            $agent_full_name .= ' '.trim($agent->first_name);
            
            /* Контакты контрагента */
            $phone = Phone::where('agent_id', '=', $counter->id)->first();
            $email = Email::where('agent_id', '=', $counter->id)->first();
            
            $rec_phone = '';
            if ($phone) {
                $rec_phone = $phone->phone;
            }
            
            $rec_email = '';
            if ($email) {
                $rec_email = $email->email;
            }   

            
            $guarantee = 'Исполнение';
            $status = 'Черновик';
            $counter->name = trim(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $counter->name));

            $content .= '"'.$order->order_date.'","'.$counter->name.'","'.$counter->inn.'",';
            $content .= '"'.$director_full_name.'","'.$rec_phone.'","'.$rec_email.'","'.$counter->address.'",';
            $content .= '"'.$order->amount.'","'.$order->bill.'","'.$order->law_id.'",';
            $content .= '"'.$guarantee.'","'.$order->auction_date.'","'.$order->guarantee_expires.'","'.$status.'"';
            $content .= PHP_EOL;
            
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете привести фактический и желаемый результаты?

Comment: сейчас скину картинку, получается я выделил пользователя, у этого пользователя несколько заявок, а отображается одна

Comment: А Вы уверены, что у пользователя несколько заявок? Если есть возможность, приведите, пожалуйста, небольшую часть БД.

Comment: @nomnoms12 скинул)

Comment: _"проблема в том, что одинаковые данные из других таблиц он заменяет"_


Что и где заменяет? Перефразируйте вопрос.